# Use polymorphism with references. Invalid initialisation of non const reference

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism

I would like to use polymorphism with references, without the `new` operator. There is one `BaseClass`, which has some (in this case one) virtual method. And the subclasses will implement it.

I've created a factory function, which creates an appropriate instance. But I get this error:

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'BaseClass&' from an rvalue of type 'SubOne'
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class SubOne : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void run() override {
        std::cout << "I am SubOne!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class SubTwo : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void run() override {
        std::cout << "I am SubTwo!" << std::endl;
    }
};

BaseClass& baseFactory(int num) {

    switch(num) {

        case 1:
            return SubOne();

        case 2:
        default:
            return SubTwo();

    }

}

void executer(BaseClass& base) {

    // code...

    base.run();

    // code...

}

int main() {

    BaseClass& base = baseFactory( 1 );

    // code...

    executer(base);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is the least of your worries. Returning a reference to a local object leads to undefined behaviour if the reference is used.

Comment: You cannot have an object factory without dynamic memory allocation. References are not magic. `std::shared_ptr`s are, use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a locally-created object from a function that returns a reference:

```
BaseClass& baseFactory(int num) {
    ...
    return SubOne(); // Not allowed
}
```

This is because the local object goes out of scope as soon as the function is over, and you end up with a hanging reference.

You should change your function to returning a dynamically-allocated object, and storing it into a smart pointer:

```
BaseClass* baseFactory(int num) {
    ...
    return new SubOne();
}

unique_ptr<BaseClass> dyn { baseFactory(1) };
```

Comment: Also, if there is a performance reason you want to avoid the new operator you can provide a custom allocator, I think to be able to provide a better answer than this we'd need to know *why* you don't want to use the heap.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the return type of `baseFactory` to `const`, you notice the following warning shows up: (Warning seen [here](http://cpp.sh/3krlr))

> In function 'const BaseClass& baseFactory(int)':
>
> 27:27: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>
> 31:27: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

As you can see, you cannot return an actual reference to a temporary variable, because as the warning says, it *IS* temporary. You cannot return a reference to something that does not exist, aka a dangling reference. Unfortunately, the only way to do this,is using pointers, aka:

```
BaseClass* baseFactory(int num) {

    switch(num) {

        case 1:
            return new SubOne();

        case 2:
        default:
            return new SubTwo();

    }

}
```

The problem with this is that the calling function, here main, must deal with cleanup, or you get a memory leak. Or, like @dasblinkenlight has included in his answer, you can use **RAII** (**R**esource **A**cquisition **I**s **I**nitialization), and hold the class in a smart pointer, where the destructor of the smart pointer will delete the object.